# In Django, how do I save inline form records one at a time after cleaning?

Tags: django, database, forms, inline

In the process of writing an inventory system, and am at the point where I am doing some validation with bookings.  X inventory line items are booked on an insertion order using an inline for line items, and each type of line item can only occur so many times for a particular day.  If a certain type occurs too many times for a given day, I have to throw an error.

So I have this working fine when adding line items one at a time.  Once it reaches the limit for that type of line item, it errors as expected.  But say I have a limit of 6 line items of type A, I'm currently at 5, and I'm trying to add 2 more, yielding a total of 7.  This should error, but it does not.

My theory is that it doesn't save to the database after each line item is cleaned.  When cleaning it checks new line item #1 and says "Room for one more!".  Then it checks new line item #2, and because new line item #1 hasn't been saved, it says, "Still room for one more!"  Then when everything is saved at once, we're over the limit.  So what I would like to be able to do is save each line item immediately after it passes muster, so that on cleaning the next line item, it will see that there is no more room and throw an error.

So in short, the question is, how can I save an inline record immediately after finding that it passes checks, so that the next inline record's validation can be based off of that record's presence in the database?  Thoughts?

Comment: Sorrry to ask, do you test the limit is reached with an '==' or with a '>' ?

Comment: Did you tried to add clean methods in the form ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: I am using a clean method for validation, but that requires a new query for each line item to see if that line item conflicts with what's in the database.  Works fine for what's there, but it doesn't factor in line items that have already been cleaned and will be added to the database.  Need these to be taken into account